# Import file from FTP site

Tags: import

I would like to Import files from an FTP site. The code below works on a test site:

```
file = Import["ftp://test:test@ftp.secureftp-test.com/pigs.xml"];
```

But when I try to Import from a commercial site using similar code:

```
file = Import["ftp://user:pwrd@hosted.datascope.reuters.com/fldr/fname.csv"]
```

I get "FetchURL::conopen: The connection to URL [address above] cannot be opened. If the URL is correct, you might need to configure your firewall program, or you might need to set a proxy in the Internet connectivity tab of the Preferences dialog (or by calling SetInternetProxy).  For HTTPS connections, you might need to inspect the authenticity of the server's SSL certificate and choose to accept it."

If I paste the same ftp string into a browser it loads the file I want.  What's wrong here?

@halirutan-I think I am using the correct user name and password.
@J.M.-I'm using Win7.
@celtschi-I saw a the back slash too at some point. I think I deleted it to get the browser to work; don't remember clearly.
@all-Thanks for all this effort.  I'm trying to digest this feedback.
@all-Tried again with various combinations of Element specifications with no success.
     Also attempted to get a file list with no success.

Comment: But you used the correct *user* and *pwrd* in the second example? You tried it in your browser **after** you deleted the cache with stored data and passwords? Can you maybe give an example with a real user and passwd combination which we may try here?

Comment: I just tried it with a file on my website and it worked. Is it possible, that it has something to do with this special website of yours?

Comment: What OS are you using? I get similar errors in Ubuntu Oneiric when trying to retrieve `ExampleData[]`, e.g. `ExampleData[{"Matrix", "WEST0479"}]`, since `ExampleData[]` seems to try to import things via FTP from the [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/Harwell-Boeing/chemwest/west0479.html).

Comment: @J.M. I have the same behavior on my Ubuntu 64 and MacOSX.

Comment: I just tried it with the `ExampleData`, too, and also got an error (Linux). However when I copied the URL into a browser, I noticed that before the file, there was an extra backslash which isn't displayed; fetching that URL from the browser failed (error 500) while without the slash it worked (for reference, the URL as copy/pasted is `ftp://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/chemwest/\
west0479.mtx.gz`). Further pasting into a terminal reveals that actually it's an escaped newline character (the browser removed the newline character, but not the `\\`). Without that, the URL works.

Comment: @celtschk, I tried `Import["ftp://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/chemwest/west0479.mtx.gz", "Graphics"]` out before as an alternative; no dice.

Comment: @J.M. Your pasted filename string still has one (or more) non-displayable chars in there. The last 8 bytes I see are `00000047h: 3F 3F 6D 74 78 2E 67 7A`, but you may get another thing instead of those `3F 3F`

Comment: @belisarius: The `6D 74 78 2E 67 7A` is just the `mtx.gz` at the end of the URL. `3F` is a question mark, which your browser (or the program you pasted it to) probably used to indicate characters it could not handle. I get as extra bytes `e2 808c e280 8b` which is valid UTF8 for the character sequence `U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER`, `U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE`. Being zero-width, you of course don't see those characters, but they certainly don't belong in the URL.

Comment: @celtschk yep. I haven't done an in-depth analysis, just wanted to warn J.M. that there is something going on in the string. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that worked for with the `west0479.mtx` example. I had the same behavior as pointed out in the comments which means both, `ExampleData[{"Matrix", "WEST0479"}]` and

```
Import["ftp://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/chemwest/west0479.mtx.gz"]
```

timed out with a `FetchURL::conopen` message.

Since my [internet connectivity](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/486) was fine (*Edit->Preferences->Internet Connectivity->Test Internet Connectivity*) I did a [clean start of Mathematica](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3274). Here in Linux this goes by starting Mathematica from the console with `-cleanstart` option.

```
Import["ftp://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/chemwest/west0479.mtx.gz", 
 "Graphics"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All credits for this go to the Wolfram support.

Comment: I can confirm this worked in a fresh session (without needing a "clean start") under Mac OS x 10.8