# import file from directory using sftp

Tags: import

I want to import a file from a directory on a ftp using sftp. I'm not sure how the command looks, but here is what I have tried (based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10717/import-file-from-ftp-site) older post):

`Import["sftp://username:password@server.com/homeDIR/folder/test.txt"];`

However, this gives me an error: `... is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification.`

Comment: The documentation for `Import` states that "When importing from a URL, Import can handle http, https, and ftp." There is no reason AFAIK to believe that `Import` would handle SFTP, which is a different protocol not closely related to FTP.

Comment: @C.E. It still remains a good question how to do this though. Is there any way to import from sftp directories? (There certainly are ways of course, just by using Run and using terminal (or other os equivalent) commands.) But is there an actual practical and reliable way to do this?