# Using SFTP directories as regular directories

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories

Is it possible to use SFTP directories in a similar way to normal directories in Mathematica? I would like it if I could Import,Export,Get,Put etc to SFTP directories just as if they were normal directories. (The fact that I can't by default might indicate that mathematica is not capable of this or that it is a difficult problem, but maybe someone found some satisfying solution.)

A similar question was asked here ([import file from directory using sftp](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75479/import-file-from-directory-using-sftp)) but it seems it was interpreted as just the question why an sftp directory does not work with Import and not as a request for whether anyone has an alternative that does work.

Alternatively is there a different way to connect to remote clusters than sftp so that we can import and export directly from Mathematica. (Sorry, I am not at all an expert in protocols and connecting to clusters.)

---

Personally I am most interested in answers that work on Ubuntu (although I am also interested in a Windows based answer.)

---

As Szabolcs pointed out this is probably best solved at the operator system level. I will come back and see whether there is a good appropriate answer for Mathemematica Stackexchange after I get something working. But probably the best answer is just a link to the equivalent stackexchange question for a unix based solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62677/best-way-to-mount-remote-folder to the problem of mounting remotes folders.

Comment: This is best solved at the operating system level, not in Mathematica. Look for a tool that can mount an SFTP directory and show it as a normal part of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX I have used [SSHFS](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS) to mount a SFTP volume locally. For Windows there is [this](https://www.expandrive.com/). It is not free and I have no experience with it.